# Ansible hostname module, set hostname based on IP address

Tags: ansible, raspberry-pi, hostname

I'm trying to use the [ansible hostname module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/hostname_module.html) to change hostname of multiple Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4. Because they are all based from the same Raspberry Pi OS image, their hostname is `raspberrypi` for all of them, what I would like to change.

My inventory is roughly like this:

```
rpi-cm4-1:
  node_number: 1
  name: rpi-cm4-1
  ansible_host: 192.168.1.101

rpi-cm4-2:
  node_number: 2
  name: rpi-cm4-2
  ansible_host: 192.168.1.102

...
```

and my playbook is like this:

```
- name: Change hostname of managed nodes
  hosts: rpi_cm4-2
  tasks:
    - name: Change hostname of managed nodes
      ansible.builtin.hostname:
        name: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].name }}"
```

When I run the playbook, the error I'm facing is this:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [rpi-cm4-2]

TASK [Change hostname of managed nodes] *****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [rpi-cm4-2]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: |-
    Command failed rc=1, out=, err=Could not set pretty hostname: Connection timed out
```

I *guess* that maybe Ansible is not using the ip address of the inventory (but it used it for gathering facts).
What could I do to make him use the IP of the inventory ?

I could not manage to make Ansible use the IP address.

The `-vvv` actually shows this:

```
TASK [Change hostname of managed nodes] ****************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ncasaux/home-lab/ansible/tpi2_rpi_cm4.tpi2_rpios.yml:75
<192.168.1.102> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: pi
<192.168.1.102> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ncasaux/.ansible/cp/ed650a3305"' 192.168.1.102 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~pi && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.1.102> (0, b'/home/pi\n', b'')
<192.168.1.102> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: pi
<192.168.1.102> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ncasaux/.ansible/cp/ed650a3305"' 192.168.1.102 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/pi/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1703118028.4996538-25006-160853801334657 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1703118028.4996538-25006-160853801334657="` echo /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1703118028.4996538-25006-160853801334657 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.1.102> (0, b'ansible-tmp-1703118028.4996538-25006-160853801334657=/home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1703118028.4996538-25006-160853801334657\n', b'')
Using module file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/hostname.py
<192.168.1.102> PUT /home/ncasaux/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-24823y1az1b7h/tmp3nxd67rj TO /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1703118028.4996538-25006-160853801334657/AnsiballZ_hostname.py
<192.168.1.102> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ncasaux/.ansible/cp/ed650a3305"' '[192.168.1.102]'
<192.168.1.102> (0, b'sftp> put /home/ncasaux/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-24823y1az1b7h/tmp3nxd67rj /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1703118028.4996538-25006-160853801334657/AnsiballZ_hostname.py\n', b'')
<192.168.1.102> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: pi
<192.168.1.102> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ncasaux/.ansible/cp/ed650a3305"' 192.168.1.102 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1703118028.4996538-25006-160853801334657/ /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1703118028.4996538-25006-160853801334657/AnsiballZ_hostname.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.1.102> (0, b'', b'')
<192.168.1.102> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: pi
<192.168.1.102> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ncasaux/.ansible/cp/ed650a3305"' -tt 192.168.1.102 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1703118028.4996538-25006-160853801334657/AnsiballZ_hostname.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.1.102> (1, b'\x1b[1;31m==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.hostname1.set-static-hostname ====\r\n\x1b[0mAuthentication is required to set the statically configured local hostname, as well as the pretty hostname.\r\nAuthenticating as: ,,, (pi)\r\nPassword: polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure\r\n\r\n{"failed": true, "msg": "Command failed rc=1, out=, err=Could not set pretty hostname: Connection timed out\\n", "invocation": {"module_args": {"name": "192.168.1.102", "use": null}}}\r\n', b'Shared connection to 192.168.1.102 closed.\r\n')
<192.168.1.102> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 192.168.1.102 closed.
<192.168.1.102> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: pi
<192.168.1.102> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ncasaux/.ansible/cp/ed650a3305"' 192.168.1.102 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1703118028.4996538-25006-160853801334657/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.1.102> (0, b'', b'')
fatal: [rpi-cm4-2]: FAILED! => changed=false
  invocation:
    module_args:
      name: 192.168.1.102
      use: null
  msg: |-
    Command failed rc=1, out=, err=Could not set pretty hostname: Connection timed out
```

So the IP seems to be used...

Comment: (a) run your playbook with `-vvv` to see exactly how ansible is connecting to your host. (b) it's not clear why you are setting a `name` variable, when you could just use `inventory_hostname`. (c) you don't need to reference `hostvars[inventory_hostname].<anything>`; you can just reference `<anything>` (i.e, `{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname}.name }}` is the same as `{{ name }}`).

Comment: Thanks for the tips @larsks.
I added results of the `-vvv` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty clearly using the ip address, so that's not the problem. It looks like ansible **is** connecting successfully, but it receiving an error when it attempts to set the system hostname.

From the error message, it looks like a permissions problem:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.hostname1.set-static-hostname ====
Authentication is required to set the statically configured local hostname, as well as the pretty hostname.
Authenticating as: ,,, (pi)
Password: polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
```

You probably need to ensure that you're running the task as `root` on the remote host:

```
- name: Change hostname of managed nodes
  hosts: rpi_cm4-2
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Change hostname of managed nodes
      ansible.builtin.hostname:
        name: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].name }}"
```

Note the addition of `become: true`, which will cause all tasks in this play to run as `root`.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed a permission issue causing this!